# Automoq create object without calling a constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, automoq

Is there a way in `Automoq` to do what `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject()` does?

I have a class that let's just say is not written in the best way and I just have to get through creating that class's object using `Automoq`, but I ran into a ctor problem. The ctor does call some database routines that I have to bypass.

Comment: Create another constructor having parameters, and call that to instantiate your object, Sorry if I understand your question wrongnly

Comment: @un-lucky It is in another assembly maintained by another team. This class is not part of my test but one of my class creates an object that depends on object of the class in question.